# You might not have permission to use this network resource

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ip, network-shares

I search the Internet for solving this problem, I see many solutions and I applied it still no hope. It's not working and I already spend too many hours.

The two computers are connected to same network . Also the IP address of second computer that i tried to access through `Run` is fixed IP address. It is not changeable.

When i am accessing an IP through `Run` it showing **"PC not accessible  you might not have permission to use this network resource."**

[image: You might not have permission to use this network resource]

I can ping that IP address and it's working. But I cannot access that IP. I tried many things like setting permission for everyone, set DNS and IP address automatically, etc. I have seen many YouTube videos, but the solutions are not working. What am I missing ?  I tried with another computer in network to access this second PC through IP address, and  can access. But from the first computer I cannot access the IP. How to solve this ?

> Edit : More details

I fixed the issue, but the next day it is showing the same massage again.  But the IP of the computer which is not connected to printer is static, so it is always the same. Please tell what are the possible errors.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?  (eg are you trying to use a second PC as a router, share files ?)  What version of Windows ?

Comment: In second pc i installed a printer . So i need to use this printer in first pc also .ican acess second pc from third pc and i can use that printer in third pc also . But i cannot acess second pc from first pc . Windows versions are same in every pc . Windows8 professional

Comment: altt this 3 computers are connected in same network and connected to same main server computer .

Comment: In that case, in general terms (I don't use Windows), you need to ensure you share the printer on the computer that its connected to.  You also want to make sure its part of the same homegroup/workgroup, and that the network Interface knows its part of this group.

Comment: i think same homegroup/workgroup .

Comment: When i am going to network section in forst computer i can see the second computer . When i am clickng the second computer it showing "-pc not accessible you might not have permission to use this network resource". Please help .

Comment: Did you share the printer on second PC explicit for the first PC?

Comment: yes . I cannot aceess anything from second pc through first pc . second pc 's printer is shred to everyone .  That's why i can acess the second pc printer from  third pc

Comment: The most important thing is to ensure that you [turned on "File and Printer Sharing"](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9884-file-printer-sharing-network-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) on the machine hosting the printer.  In addition to that, Windows network sharing via a workgroup will always work much more gracefully if your have an identical username/password on each workstation. If you are using a Microsoft account, that part is rather easy.  If not, you will need to configure them manually on each machine.

Comment: i didn't understand . Why the printer connected to the second pc is not accessible in first pc and it is accessible in third pc ? . All these computers are connected in same network .

Comment: Because the machines on your workgroup might be configured differently. We are always glad to help, but did you already check the things that I asked you about? Did you ensure that you [turned on "File and Printer Sharing"](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9884-file-printer-sharing-network-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) on the machine hosting the printer? Also, did you verify that you have an identical username/password that exists on **every** workstation?

Comment: @Run5k thank you friend. I solve the issue . I don't know it is good method or not  For to solve this i go to second computer in which printer is installed , i take network and sharing center -> Advance share center . In this turn on network discovery and turn on printers  and sharing is already on , i tick use user account and password to connect to other computer . After that all issue is solved . Thank you .

Comment: @Run5k . but today morning i come the same situation arrivied . Now i canot acees printer

Comment: If I may, you never did answer one of my questions:  did you verify that you have an identical username/password that exists on every workstation?

Comment: friend actulally i didn't have more knowledge in this thing . How i can check work station have same username and password .

Comment: from all of these computer i can login administrator of the server . And this user name and password is same .

Comment: No problem… it is relatively simple:  does the computer that is hosting the printer have the exact same userid/password as the one you are using on the remote computer?  For example, if I login to the remote computer with an account called **John** and a password of **LetMeIn**, is there also an account called **John** using the same password that already exists on the computer hosting the printer?  In other words, on the computer that is hosting the printer you could *also* login locally by using **John** and a password of **LetMeIn**.

Comment: no .Both of us having different username . For example printer connected computer user name is John , and the computer in which i try to access computer have user name smith .

Comment: If that's the case, it is probably the key to eliminating your problem.  Create a local account *on the computer that is hosting the printer* with an identical username/password to the one that exists on the remote computer.

Comment: there is no similar account . I need to make similar account ?. Also what i need if i want to access printer from more computers

Comment: Yes, you would need to [make an identical account](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5440-add-user-account-windows-10-a.html#option3): same user name and password.  On my home network, I ensure that each member of my family has the same local login on every computer so that they can easily share files, folders, and printers.  If you want to do this from more computers, you would potentially need to do the same.

Comment: really thank you friend . Could you please write this in answe section , so that i can accept and for other people also it is useful .

Comment: Always glad to help, but you should double-check to ensure that it works in your environment before we draw any conclusions.  It *should*, but since I'm not actually there myself there could be other variables in the equation.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress... did that solution work for you?

Comment: it's working friend.Really sorry for the late  reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to ensure that you turned on **File and Printer Sharing** on the machine hosting the printer:

> 1. Right-click on your network icon in the Notification Area and select **Open Network and Sharing Center**
> 2. Select **Change advanced sharing settings** on the upper-left
>
>    [image: Change advanced sharing settings]
> 3. Expand the appropriate network profile (typically **Private**)
> 4. Select the radio button to **Turn on file and printer sharing**
>
>    [image: Turn on file and printer sharing]
> 5. Select the **Save changes** button (and acknowledge the UAC prompt, if necessary)

(Source:  [Turn On File and Printer Sharing in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49753-turn-off-file-printer-sharing-windows-10-a.html))

In addition to that, Windows network sharing via a workgroup will always work much more gracefully if your have an **identical username/password on each workstation**. If you are using Microsoft accounts, that part is rather easy and is essentially already done. If not, you will need to create the accounts manually on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

As in my problem, I found the solution. Actualy this thing is related to the MS protection.
These are the steps:

1. Go to User Accounts.
2. Click or tap on Manage Windows Credentials. Or, go to Credentials Manager then Windows Credentials tab.
3. Click or tap on Add a Windows credential.
4. Enter the remote server computer name as the Internet or network address (192.168.1.2 in my case), and then enter the user name (root in my case) and password (empty in my case).

I hope so it be useful.